# how can i passing value to combobox in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

i have combobox in one screen(namely 1) and i need to pass the selected value of the combobox to the another combobox which is in the another screen(namely 2) and the passed value should be selected by default.

Comment: post the relevant code (for both comboboxes) and you might get detailed responses

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms (if both comboboxes have plain strings or same set of objects in their data providers):

```
combobox2.selectedItem = combobox1.selectedItem;
```

If that is not the case, you will have to get a mapping from items of first combobox to the second one.